# Dificuldade com belongsto Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

Estou fazendo um projeto com Laravel e estou com dificuldade no relacionamento
Poderiam me ajudar?

Tenho duas entidades no meu banco que são Aluno e Situacao.

Aluno tem esses atributos: id, nome, serie, email.
Situacao tem esses atributos: id, nome_situacao.

O relacionamento é de 1 para N. E a chave primária da tabela
Situacao vai para a tabela Aluno como estrangeira.

Estou fazendo isso no Laravel 5.6 e no cadastro do aluno não estou conseguindo popular um select puxando a situação dele que seriam essas três:
Matriculado, Bolsita, Inadimplente.

Vi na doc do Laravel que nesse caso seria necessário usar o belongsto, mas
não entendi direito.
Vou postar as duas models, o controller e a view.

--- MODEL DE ALUNO ---

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Escola;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;


class Aluno extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'nome', 'serie', 'email', 
        
    ];     

    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

}
```

--- MODEL DE SITUACAO ---

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Escola;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Situacao extends Model
{
     protected $fillable = [
        'nome_situacao'
    ];
    protected $table = 'situacoes';


    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

}
```

-- ESSE É O CONTROLLER

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Escola;

use Validator; 
use App\Models\Escola\Aluno;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;


class AlunoController extends Controller{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $alunos = Aluno::latest()->paginate(10);

        return view('escola.alunos.index',compact(
            'alunos', 'nome', 'serie', 'email'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1 ) -1) * 5);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('escola.alunos.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */


    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        request()->validate([
            'nome' => 'required',
            'serie' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            
            
        ]);

        Aluno::create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('alunos.index')
                    ->with('success', 'Aluno cadastrado com sucesso!');

    } 

}
```

-- MINHA VIEW --

```
@extends('adminlte::page')

@section('title', 'Cadastro')

@section('content_header')
    <center>
    <br>
    <h3 style="margin-top: -30px;">Gerenciador de Alunos</h3>
    </center>
@stop

@section('content')
<br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <div class="pull-right">
            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target=" .bd-example-modal-lg">Incluir Aluno</button>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                
                <form action="{{ route('alunos.store') }}" method="POST">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="container box box-success">
                <br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <strong>Nome do Novo Aluno:</strong>
                            <input type="text" name="nome" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite o nome..." required="ON">
                    </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                        <strong>Serie do Novo Aluno:</strong>
                            <input type="email" name="serie" 
      class="form-control" placeholder="Digite o nome..." required="ON">
                    </div>
         
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <strong>Email do Novo Aluno:</strong>
                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite o email..." required="ON">
                    </div>
         
<div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <strong>Selecione a Situação</strong>
                            <select name="situacao_id" class="form-control" required="ON">
                            <option value="">Clique aqui</option>
                            
                            @foreach ($classsituacao_array as $situacoes_id)
                                <option value="{{$situacoes_id->id}}" > {{$situacoes_id->nome_situacao}}</option>
                            @endforeach 
                            </select>    

                        </div>
<div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                        </div> 

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                        <center><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button></center>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sic btn-success btn-block btn-flat ">

                            Enviar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                </form>
                </div>   
              </div>
            </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
            <!--Mensagem de sucesso ao cadastrar-->

        @if ($message = Session::get('success'))

            <div class="alert alert-success">
                <p>{{ $message }}</p>
            </div>
        
       @endif

    <head>
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" class="init">

            $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#tobarril').DataTable({
                    "language": {
                    "lengthMenu": "Visualizando _MENU_  itens por página",
                    "zeroRecords": "Item não encontrado",
                    "info": "Visualizando página _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
                    "infoEmpty": "Nenhum item a ser exibido",
                    "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado from _MAX_ total records)"
                        }
                    } 
                );
            } );
        </script>

    </head>
            
    <br>
    <div class="container box box-success">
    </div>
    <br>
        <table id="tobarril" class="table table-bordered"> 
         
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><center>Nome</center></th>
            <th><center>Serie</center></th>
            <th><center>Email</center></th>
            <th><center>Situacao</center></th>
            <th width="150px"><center>Ação</center></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach ($alunos as $aluno)
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><center>{{ $aluno->id }}</center></td>
            <td><center>{{ $aluno->nome }}</center></td>
            <th><center>{{ $aluno->serie }}</center></th>
            <th><center>{{ $aluno->email }}</center></th>
            <th><center>{{ $aluno->situacao }}</center></th>



 <center>
                <form action="{{ route('alunos.destroy',$aluno->id) }}" method="POST">

                
 
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('alunos.edit',$aluno->id) }}">Editar</a>


                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')

   
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Deletar</button>
                </form>
            </center>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        @endforeach
    </table>


   {!! $alunos->links() !!}



@endsection
```

Da forma que estou fazendo, está retornando o id da situacão na view, porém eu queria que informasse o registro da situação (Matriculado, Bolsista, Inadimplente). Consegui fazer isso usando Providers, mas não é a maneira correta
de popular o select, porque se por exemplo eu tirar da view a situação bolsista ela soma do select, quando deveria está no banco. Ou seja, dessa forma ele popula o select de acordo com o que eu mantenho na view do Crud de Situação.

Comment: O aluno pode ter mais de uma situação?

Comment: Sim, ele pode ter: Matriculado, Bolsista, Inadimplente.

Answer (score -1):

Se o aluno pode possuir várias situações então "aluno hasMany (possui muitas) situacao", e "situacao belongsTo(pertence a) aluno", lembrando que é necessário realizar o mapeamento de ambos os lados para que o mesmo funcione da maneira esperada.

Segue exemplo das relações nas models(classes):

**Classe Aluno**

> public function situacao(){
>
> return $this->hasMany(Situacao::class);
>
> }

**Classe Situacao**

> public function aluno(){
>
> return $this->belongsTo(Aluno::class);
>
> }